# Create DB from a dump.sql file with NodeJS (Express) + TypeScript

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, express

I'm using Express and TypeScript to build an app. This app is already configured to work with MySQL but my problem is that I don't know yet how to create the database based on a dump.sql file.

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test;

USE test;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS testData;

CREATE TABLE testData(
  name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  valid INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (name)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO testDataVALUES
('Peter', NULL),
.
.
.
```

This is what I'm trying to find, passing the sql file as variable or something after being exported or something from it file because with the .sql extension I can't export the file.

```
connection.query(dump.sql, function (err, rows, fields) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log('The database was successfully created..');
});
```

So is it possible to do it? I would like to know HOW because I don't see any documentation up to date related to this... otherwise I will create the DB manually in xampp and after use the db but I think this is not the way to do it.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

If this is a dump file produced by `mysqldump` then you should just [execute a shell command](https://stackabuse.com/executing-shell-commands-with-node-js/) to run the mysql client and source that dump file as its input.

The reason is that dump files may contain [mysql client builtin commands](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html) that are not recognized by the MySQL Server. They are preprocessed by the mysql client.